# Skyrim miscellaneous quests point to wrong part of map

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm playing Skyrim on PC.  I've completed the main storyline, and I'm trying to complete a lot of unfinished Miscellaneous quests.  But for some reason, my quest tracking is not working properly.

I'm trying to track some a few old misc quests, but the quest tracking only seems to be tracking the topmost misc quest.  To be clear, I am tracking both misc quests as a whole and also tracking specific ones within that category.

Specifically, I'm trying to Clear Redbelly Mine of Spiders, but selecting that quest does not show any waypoint on my map.  And if I select "Show on Map" it goes to a completely unrelated part of the map.  It centers my map at the location of my topmost misc quest (a dragon bounty).  The really weird thing is only some of the misc quests are broken like this.  For example, one misc quest is "Kill the leader of Pinemoon Cave", which correctly sets a waypoint to (undiscovered) Pinemoon Cave.

So what is going wrong with my Misc quests, and how can I fix this?  I'd really rather not have to look up map locations outside of the game itself, but I'm open to console commands to fix/reset anything that went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This would happen to me commonly - sometimes for primary quests, as well.

In most cases, the map marker would be pointing me towards the next "level transition", say, a door that had a loading screen while I passed through. If you find an alternate path, and circumnavigate the door, the marker will still point you to the door - even if you are closer to your objective.

Other times, Skyrim is just buggy. There is not much you can do, there.

I would recommend simply looking the quest or location up on the Elder Scrolls Wiki, and placing your own map markers. [You will find the page on Redbelly Farm here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Redbelly_Mine_%28Skyrim%29).

There are reports of the markers fixing themselves as you get closer to your objective. So perhaps head that way, and see if anything changes.

Answer (score 2):

From personal experience I can say that markers start behaving weirdly if you have too many active quests. 
I'd suggest ticking off a few of those quests, or just doing the ones with the pointers working first.